# how to integrate Cybersource with magento?

Tags: magento

How to integrate Cybersource with magento . just tried this extension .
Url:- https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-extension.html

This gives me error

> Gateway request error:  Security Data : UsernameToken authentication
>   failed.

please advise on how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: try to contact devoloper using "email" button in the extension page.

Comment: It seems Auth token Issue, Confirm your authentication and try again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?